# how do I change the default value of form control in react bootstrap

Tags: react-bootstrap

I am using react bootstrap for an application. For input fields I am using FormControl. How do I change the default increase/decrease value when I hit the up or down button in the control box? I want to change it to 0.1 but the current value is 1.
Thank you

[image]